# сохранение на одном строке

Tags: java, mysql, spring

**когда добавлю комментария оно сохраняется в одном же строке.Вот код который сохраняет в беззе**

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/addComment",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addComment(@ModelAttribute("comment")Comment comment, @RequestParam("id")int id, @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Answer answer,Task task) {
    answer.setId(id);
    comment.setAnswer(answer);
    comment.setUserEmail(userDetails.getUsername());
    commentRepository.save(comment);
    task.setId(id);
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("id",id);
    return "redirect:/findAnswerByTaskId";
}
```

**return идет вот сюда**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/findAnswerByTaskId", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findAnswerByTaskId(@RequestParam("id") int id, @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails, ModelMap map) {
    taskId=id;
    List<AnswerPicture> allByAnswerId = answerPictureRepository.findAllByAnswer_Task_Id(id);
    List<Answer> allByTaskId = answerRepository.findAllByTaskId(id);
    map.addAttribute("allByAnswerId", allByAnswerId);
    map.addAttribute("idAnswer", answerId);
    map.addAttribute("allByTaskId", allByTaskId);
    map.addAttribute("newComment", new Comment());
    map.addAttribute("id",id);
    return "answerResult";
}
```

**и это в jsp**

```
<spring:form action="/addComment" method="post" modelAttribute="newComment">
    <input type="hidden" value="${id.id}" name="id">
    <spring:textarea path="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value="comment"/>
</spring:form>
```

Comment: а что вы ожидаете ? как должно хранится ?

Comment: если добавить несколько комментариев он сохраняет все комментарии в том же строке то есть если добавить комментария под номером 1 и добавить комментария под номером 2 этот коммент который был под номером 2 сохраняет в том же строке как и на первом

Comment: Этот код без пояснения, невозможно понять в чем вопрос

Comment: скажите какая часть объяснить чтобы стало вам понятно

Comment: Убедитесь, что передаёте разные comment в этот метод. И добавьте в вопрос описание классов Comment, Answer и интерфейса commentRepository